# TestThat cannot locate the file

Tags: r, testthat

I am building a plumber app, and plan to use TestThat for my unit testing. However, when I run `devtools::test()`, it says `File does not exist: test.R`.

My file name is test.R and my test file is already test-test.R.

Here is my testthat.R file:

```
library(testthat)

test("finalproject")
test_check("finalproject")
```

And I also put: `source("../../R/test.R")` on my test-test.R already.

My question is how does TestThat define the code path? Can we define it manually?

Thanks!

Comment: are you building this as a package?

Comment: @SymbolixAU no, I will just run it as a plumber app only. How do we define it if it is not a package?

Comment: If you have created `"finalproject"` as a package: Tests are assumed to be located in either the `inst/tests/` or `tests/testthat` directory. Otherwise you can run all tests in a given directory with `testthat::test_dir`

Comment: as @EnriquePérezHerrero points out I think you'll want `testthat::test_dir("path/to/test/dir/")`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now! EnriquePérezHerrero and SymbolixAU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created `"finalproject"` as a package: Tests are assumed to be located in either the `inst/tests/` or `tests/testthat` directory.
You can also run all tests in a given directory with `testthat::test_dir("path/to/test/dir/")`